# Multiple line Windows Batch File issue

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have a batch file with following contents

Line 1
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\SysMgt\bmc\ipmish.exe" -interactive  -ip 192.168.1.5 -u root -p Password

after this it goes to prompt 
IPMISH>

Line 2
Power On

I am not sure how to pass this command line 2 to the prompt IPMISH>

**What i have tried**
1. adding to second line simply does nothing

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A batch file does not work in this way - each line is interpreted as a command to execute in turn. When you're calling `ipmish.exe`, it will block the rest of the batch until the process has ended.

In order to achieve what you want to do, you could to look at the documentation for `ipmish.exe` and see if there is a method of scripting for it (As you're able to specify `-interactive` I get the impression there may be a scripted interface). Alternately, you could look into using a different software solution to execute this as a 'batch', but with the ability to send keys to it, such as AutoIt or similar.